# Can I declare and initialize a variable in an Ant script?

Tags: java, ant

In Ant, can I create a target that contains something like a variable that represents a path?

For example, something like the following pseudo target:

```
<target name="initPath">
    Path = "${basedir}/../../myProject/Project/"
</target>
```

Where **Path** is my variable and is initializated to specific value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Ant build scripts are written in XML. To create a *property* has to be in XML style, so instead of this:

```
some_prop="some value"
```

It is this:

```
<property name="some_prop"  value="some value"/>
```

Properties can contain periods, and I recommend using them as name separators:

```
<property name="some.prop"  value="some value"/>
```

How do you declare a constant? Here:

```
<property name="some.prop"  value="some value"/>
```

That's because once a property is set, it cannot be changed.

This way, you can do something like this:

```
<property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>
<property name="some.prop" value="some value"/>
```

Let's say that the `build.properties` file contains this line:

```
some.prop="Some other value"/>
```

Now, when you run your Ant build file, the value of `some.prop` will be "Some other value", and the `<property name="some.prop" value="some value"/>` won't change it. I could even do this:

```
$ ant -Dsome.prop="A completely different value"
```

And this value of the `some.prop` property will override what I have in my build.properties file and what I have in my Ant build file.

This is a very nice feature. It allows me to set a default value that developers can override:

```
<property name="copy.verbose"  value="false"/>
...
<copy todir="${copy.to.dir}"
    verbose="${copy.verbose}">
    <fileset dir="${copy.from.dir}"/>
</copy>
```

By default, when my `copy` task runs, it runs in non-verbose mode which is what I want. However, let's say I am having a few problems with my build, and I want to see exactly what is being copied, I could do this:

```
$ ant -Dcopy.verbose=true
```

And, now my copy tasks will show me all the files being copied.

---

A *path* is a way to declare something like `$CLASSPATH` or `$PATH` in the command line. You can predeclare a *path* with an id, and then use it later:

```
<javac destdir="${main.destdir}"
    srcdir="${main.srcdir}">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Here I'm adding a classpath. This is using `<fileset/>` to create a classpath based upon all of the jars in my `${lib.dir}` directory.

I can also do this:

```
<path id="main.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<javac destdir="${main.destdir}"
    srcdir="${main.srcdir}"
    classpathref="main.classpath"/>
```

Here, I predeclare my `main.classpath` and then use that later in my `<javac>` task.

You should read up on Ant in the on line Ant Manual. There is a semi-decent introduction in the manual which might help clarify a few issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can define a [property](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) in Ant script.

Unfortunately it is not a variable, since they are immutable. You can set a value to it, but you cannot change it during your script execution.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914743/how-to-assign-value-to-variable-and-reuse-it-ant) you can see an example of assigning value to a property.

Update.
You can use path [task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path). For example:

```
    <path id="combinedPath">
        <path path="${toString:oldPath}"/>
        <path path="my.jar"/>
    </path>

    <path id="reanamePath">
        <path path="${toString:oldPath}"/>
    </path>
```

If you change path in one target you can definitely access it in another one.

Comment: Ok this is good for me because I need a constant and not a variable. The only thing is the following question: "I have setted the value of a constant in my initPath target, in a second time can I use this constant in some other target?"

Comment: @AndreaNobili Just edited my post with an answer for this comment

Answer (score 0):

Ant has [classpath-like support built-in](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path).

In general you wouldn't use a property for this functionality.

Please consider reading the Ant documentation; this is Ant 101 and it'll be quicker in the long run if you spend some time with the docs and figuring out the Ant way of doing things.

Comment: mmm I had just considered this option but I think that is not a good idea for me because I have to initialize 2 differnt version based on the operating system used...

Comment: @AndreaNobili Oh, I misread your question, I thought it was a classpath. Either way, it can go into a conditional. Relative paths are a recipe for disaster, though; consider creating a path and creating relative paths off of a defined path, using a system property, etc. instead.